# HttpContext in console application

Tags: c#

Why HttpContext is not found in c# console application.
System.Web in Console application and System.Web in asp.net Application is same or not?
thanx

Comment: Add reference to your project

Comment: just adding reference not working.
I not found the System.Web reference

Comment: Clearly you can reference System.Web from console application (may need to change target framework to full from client profile)... But what you *actually* want to achieve?

Comment: HttpContext has a property to get absolute URL instead of relative url .
That is ht tp://local host/index.html instead of ht tp://local host.
Is there any option to find theories same in console application

Answer (score 1):

using HttpContext in console application is not possible.
it is meant to be used in web application. to use HttpContext you need to make asp.net application and not console application.
If you want to use it for **HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath** like function then you can go for **Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location**

Answer (score 1):

you can implement a fake httpcontex using IHttpContextAccessor i'm using .net core 2.1

```
public class FakeHttpContext : IHttpContextAccessor
{
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;
   

    public FakeHttpContext()
    {
        _httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
          _httpContext.Request.Scheme = "https";       
    }

    public HttpContext HttpContext
    {
        get { return _httpContext; }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}}
```

then inject it to your program like this

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
         services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, FakeHttpContext >();
        services
            .AddSingleton<IAnyClass, Anyclass>()
            .BuildServiceProvider()
            .GetService<IAnyClass>().Execute();//create a method to execute
    }
```

Remember this is a fake context this is not a web application so the context comes empty you can fill in values like
_httpContext.Request.Scheme = "https"; for example
so you can access them later using injection on your "Anyclass"

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext is for use in ASP.Net applications. A console application is not an ASP.Net application and therefore you are not working in a web context.

Comment: Actually ASP.NET 5 [can be hosted on IIS or self-hosted in a custom process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx) so a console app could be an _ASP.Net application_ as much as a [Windows service](http://blog.2mas.xyz/asp-net-5-self-hosting-the-application/)

Comment: so is there no way to use System.Web.HttpContext on console application?